# How do I set the configuration of the port 8000 on nginx with docker?

Tags: nginx, docker

I need to get callback url like http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback.

But the port 8000 is closed in myapp.

How can I set the configuration to open the port 8000 on nginx with docker?

docker version : 17.03.1-ce

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        image: my_web
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - webnet
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        image: my_app
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
        networks:
            - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: Just `- "8000:80"`?

Comment: It seems work, thank you!!